# Fill a div with an image (object-fit question)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have images that are dynamically pulled and cannot be certain of the image size or ratio of the image.

Using bootstrap4 (and wordpress) i'm trying to scale the image so that it fills the width and height of the div, and if possible maintain the aspect ratio (its ok if the image gets portions cutoff).

My image is currently breaking the height of the div and the image will size outside of the div.

```css
.blog-home {
  max-width: 570px;
  max-height: 225px;
}

.blog-home img {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height: 210px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row article">
  <div class="col-md-6 blog-home">
    <picture width="778" height="312" class="attachment-large size-large wp-post-image">
      <source type="image/webp" srcset="..." sizes="(max-width: 778px) 100vw, 778px">
      <img src="..." sizes="(max-width: 778px) 100vw, 778px">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

My  tags are dynamically replaced with  tags. I can't sort out how to fix this without breaking the responsive-ness of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Then I would suggest that you use background-size: cover. Here is the definition according to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp.

Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

Answer (score 0):

Use **Cover** to resize the background image to cover the entire container.

Here is an example link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to cut or crop the images somewhere in the wordpress, here is [a good read on why and how](https://visualcomposer.com/blog/wordpress-image-sizes-guide/) it can be achieved. In case your images are already in the Media Library - use Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to fix all of them in one click.

I think there are a lot of styles involved in the case, so it won't be so easy to get which exact part of it breaks the output without inspecting the full source, however in the worst case you could add `.blog-home {overflow:hidden}` to cut all what goes outside the div.